# Tablesorter filter - multiple drop down in the same table header cell

Tags: jquery, html, tablesorter

I am using Tablesorter filter widget in my project. It is working fine with one drop down list in a table header.

Now I want Two(2) drop down list in the same table header cell.

My current code like [edited] -

```
<table>
<thead>
    <th> 
      <span class="filter-select filter-parsed" data-sorter="false" data-placeholder="Option_1.."></span> 
      <span class="filter-select filter-parsed" data-sorter="false" data-placeholder="Option_2.."></span>
    </th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
       <span title="test">Option 1 Value</span>
       <span title="opt">Option 2 Value</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
      <span title="test1">Option 1 Value1</span>
      <span title="opt1">Option 2 Value1</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
      <span title="test2">Option 1 Value2</span>
      <span title="opt2">Option 2 Value2</span>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Option 1 drop down will show -
test 
test1 
test2

Option 2 drop down will show -
opt 
opt1 
opt2

When user select 'test' from 1st drop down, it will display the following values. If users select other value it will bring related values from the displayed values.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th> 
          <span class="filter-select filter-parsed" data-sorter="false" data-placeholder="Option_1.."></span> 
          <span class="filter-select filter-parsed" data-sorter="false" data-placeholder="Option_2.."></span>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
           <span title="test">Option 1 Value</span>
           <span title="opt">Option 2 Value</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

From the above displayed value, if user select 'opt1' from dropdown no value will display but if select 'opt', it will display the above value.

How can I add another drop down in the same table header which will get data from another `<span>` element from same data cell?

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to write a custom [`filter_formatter`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-formatter) for the column; but first ask yourself, will this be a good user experience? If you do add two selects, do they "AND" or "OR" their choices for the column?

Comment: @Mottie, this is a separate column, so I can say it will be 'OR' choice. The reason for this, in the same column I am showing two different value. So, it will depend on user and they can select either any dropdown at a time and it will filter the value

Comment: The example HTML is only showing one value. Would you please provide a "more complete" example and include a step-by-step process of what is expected when the user selects one option, then a second option. Will this be applied to multiple columns?

Comment: @Mottie, please see the edited question with example

Comment: It would be much easier to implement the two dropdowns *outside* of the table.

Comment: @thank Mottie, I will do this or I will use separate header